# Remove spaces only certain places not everywhere

Tags: java, printing, line, spaces, fileinputstream

I am taking in txt from a txt file and trying to store it in an arraylist. In the txt file the  which mean ballot are not together instead the teacher placed it on a separate line. So we have to get all of the ballots together but i am not able to get them to be all together she placed the first ballot on the line like in example below. And we have to make the rest of them together. I am using a fileinputstream to collect the txt from the textfile.

the text looks like this :

> ```
> person 1 
> person 2 
> person 3
> <b> 1 2 3 
> <b> 
> 1
> 3
> 2
> ```

I want it to look like this

> ```
> person 1
> person 2 
> person 3
> <b> 1 2 3 
> <b> 1 3 2
> ```

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String fileName = keyboard.next();
File file = new File(fileName);
ArrayList<String> ballot;
 ballot = new ArrayList<String>();  
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
DataInputStream ds = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ds));
// Pattern p;
// Matcher m;
String strLine;
String inputText = "";
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    ballot.add(strLine);    
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but your post is unintelligible.  Can't tell what the original data looks like, what you want it to look like, or what goes on inside ballot.add().  And you should have a Java tag.

Comment: I made changes to it. ballot.add() adds the text from the file into an Arraylist sorry

Comment: Are the `person 1` lines input and the `<b> 1 2 3` lines output? It's hard to tell. Also, I can't see anything in your code generating the output, I think you forgot to post that part.

Comment: what rule are you wanting to follow for the replacement?  Your last comment makes it seem like you just want to turn `\n<br>` into ` <br>`, but if we aren't sure we don't know how to help you.

Comment: I am trying to take in text and store it into an arraylist. But some of the lines with the <b> are not together with there number. I am trying to get the <b> to be with the number they are assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();`. Each time you have a token `String t`, call `sb.append(t.trim()).append(' ');`. When done with parsing your file, call `sb.toString();`. If you want to add newlines here and there, use `sb.append('\n');`.

If you want an array of your tokens, you should use an `ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>;` Each time you have a set of token s making a line, use `al.add(s);` When done, call `String[] result = al.toArray(new String[al.length]);` You will need to concatenate your set of tokens into s for each line.